# Ruby chaining with bang

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to write this excerpt of code without using an assignment?

`self.name = self.name.to_s.squeeze(' ').strip`

I have tried using bang versions of the methods, but couldn't use very well since they return `nil` if the operation didn't perform any changes (instead of returning `self`).

Comment: wouldn't the `to_s` foil your efforts anyway?

Comment: What does "use attribution" mean?

Comment: `to_s` is used to "typecast" `nil` to `""`. This saves some lines of error handling, and is a convention used in Ruby.

Comment: Attribution means attribution. I wanna know if it is possible to use a chain using destructive methods to remove the aesthetically unpleasant self.name = self.name etc

Comment: If you want to know how to write this without an attribution, it would be nice to know what an attribution is. That term doesn't appear anywhere in the Ruby Language Specification nor in any Ruby books or Ruby documentation. It's also not a well-known programming term, and the usual meaning makes no sense in this context.

Comment: Ok. I wasn't aware of my mistake. "Attribution" is a term in my language (portuguese). I had forgotten the term used in english and I think I have been the victim of a false cognate. So, "attribution" means "assignment". I hope that clarifies my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to tap the whole thing. So it would be something like:

```
str.tap {|x| x.squeeze!(' ')}.tap(&:strip!)
```

This is not something I would generally recommend doing. Even if you have a dire need for mutation, the best code clarity comes from using the methods the way they were designed:

```
str.squeeze!(' ')
str.strip!
```

If this is inconvenient, consider whether you really need the mutation.

Comment: Interesting, Chuck, though I'll +1 for almost any answer containing `tap`.  I hadn't thought of using that in situations where I had wished `delete` would return what's left rather than what's deleted.  But wait! You haven't stuffed that into `@name`.

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want to avoid assignment you *could* do this:

```
self.name = 'This  is a    test  '

[['squeeze!', ' '], 'strip!'].each { |cmd| self.name.send(*cmd) }

self.name
# => "This is a test"
```

Comment: Very inventive, @Uri, though this is pretty close to assignment (as reflected by your choice of italics?).

Answer (score 1):

For a one-liner with no (Ruby) attributions and without tap:

```
a.name && (a.name.squeeze!(' ') || a.name).strip!
```

e.g.:

```
$ irb
2.1.1 :001 > class A
2.1.1 :002?>   def name=(name)
2.1.1 :003?>     puts "setting name=#{name.inspect}"
2.1.1 :004?>     @name = name
2.1.1 :005?>     end
2.1.1 :006?>   attr_reader :name
2.1.1 :007?>   end
 => nil 
2.1.1 :008 > a = A.new
 => #<A:0x007fdc909d6df8> 
2.1.1 :009 > a.name = '  and   she    was  '
setting name="  and   she    was  "
 => "  and   she    was  " 
2.1.1 :010 > a.name && (a.name.squeeze!(' ') || a.name).strip!
 => "and she was" 
2.1.1 :011 > a.name
 => "and she was" 
2.1.1 :012 > a.name = 'and   she    was'
setting name="and   she    was"
 => "and   she    was" 
2.1.1 :013 > a.name && (a.name.squeeze!(' ') || a.name).strip!
 => nil 
2.1.1 :014 > a.name = 'and she was '
setting name="and she was "
 => "and she was " 
2.1.1 :015 > a.name && (a.name.squeeze!(' ') || a.name).strip!
 => "and she was"
```